# Access child data in parent component

Tags: svelte

How can I get access to **child** data in a **parent** component?

This is the **parent** component:

```html
<script>
  import Search from './components/Search.svelte'
</script>

<Search />
```

This is the **child** component:

```html
<script>
  export let term
</script>

<input bind:value={term} />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the parent you can do

```html
<script>
 import Search from './components/Search.svelte'
 let term
</script>

<Search bind:term/>
```

That way the `term` in the parent will be synchronized with the one in the Search component.

Another approach is to get a reference to the entire component

```html
<script>
 import Search from './components/Search.svelte'
 let searchComponent
</script>

<Search bind:this={searchComponent}/>
```

and then you can access exported props and functions using `searchComponent.***`